# Forbidden, Http.status=403 with jdbcAuthentication()

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, spring-jdbc

May be i am doing any silly mistake.
After i configure authentication using `jdbcAuthentication()` getting the following error (in the bottom of this )after i log in through chrome.
**The same works for `inMemoryAuthentication()`**

Works when i have this -

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("pass").roles("REGISTERED_USER").and().withUser("admin")
            .password("pass").roles("ADMIN");
        
}
```

Here is my code -

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FplUserOperationAuthentication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select m.username as username, m.password as password, "
                    + "m.enabled as enabled from stackoverflow.users_main m where m.username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select a.username as username, a.role as authority "
                    + "from stackoverflow.authorities a where a.username = ?");
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user-profile/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user-profile/users/**").hasAnyRole("REGISTERED_USER","ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll().and().formLogin()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

**Application.properties** -

```
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
spring.application.name=fpl-user-operations
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include = *
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/ORCLPDB
spring.datasource.username = FPLADMIN
spring.datasource.password = oracle1
spring.devtools.add-properties = false
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

**SQL** -

```
alter session set current_schema = stackoverflow;
create table users_main 
(
    username varchar2(20) primary key,
    password varchar2(20),
    enabled char(1)
);

create table authorities
(
    username varchar2(20),
    role varchar2(15),
    
    constraint authorities_c1 foreign key (username) references users_main (username)

);
```

**SQL DATA**

**TABLE users_main**
[image]

**TABLE Authorities**
[image]

ERROR WHEN I ACCESS A API, after i try to login with username as "user" and password as "pass". -

**ERROR** -

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Jun 21 12:18:32 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
```

ERROR IN CONSOLE -

```
2021-06-21 14:49:11.520 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2021-06-21 14:49:11.520 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2021-06-21 14:49:11.521 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2021-06-21 14:49:11.521 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2021-06-21 14:49:11.537 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2021-06-21 14:49:11.538 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2021-06-21 14:49:11.538 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
2021-06-21 14:49:11.538 DEBUG 11856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

**NOTE - However if i give wrong credentials intentionally, it does say "Bad Credentials"**

Comment: let me know if any extra info is needed

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the exact reason, if anyone has any idea. Please let me know.

Changes - In DB i appended **ROLE** in front of all type of authorities/roles
[image]

So instead of **"REGISTERED_USER"**, i now have **"ROLE_REGISTERED_USER"**.

Found it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-jdbc-authentication)

I did not find appending **ROLE** explicitly mentioned as a protocol. So i missed that.

My Authorization method -

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user-profile/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user-profile/users/**").hasAnyRole("REGISTERED_USER","ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll().and().formLogin()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Comment: In Spring Security, a role is equivalent to an authority prefixed with "ROLE_". When you were using an in-memory user store, you specified `.roles("ADMIN")`. This means the user got the authority `ROLE_ADMIN`. When using JDBC, you simply gave the user the authority `ADMIN`, which is different, since it is not a role. If you did not want to use roles, you could keep the user with the authority `ADMIN` and change `.hasAnyRole("ADMIN")` to `.hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")`.

Comment: what is the main diff between ROLE and AUTHORITY.
One main diff obviously is that a role is read as a "ROLE_" prefixed to the actual role.

But are both same in sense of the purpose they serve ? 
why i say this is because in spring doc it says we read it like this from db - 
`.authoritiesByUsernameQuery(select email,authority from authorities where email = ?`  but we can ultimately use it by `.hasAnyRole()` method. @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana

Answer (score 0):

You have not included password encoder in the configure method

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            **.passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder())**
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select m.username as username, m.password as password, "
                    + "m.enabled as enabled from stackoverflow.users_main m where m.username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select a.username as username, a.role as authority "
                    + "from stackoverflow.authorities a where a.username = ?");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think since i have it declared as @Bean, spring auto configures that. Nevertheless, i did try. But same issue. :(

Very strange

Comment: If that did not work, I would check the datatype of the "enabled" field in user_main table. I have seen boolean type. Since you are using MySQL (TINYINT), should you be storing 0 or 1?

create table users_main(
 username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
 password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
 enabled BIT(1) not null
);

Comment: Really appreciate the effort you took to read my problem. Nevertheless, i found the issue, Checkout my answer to this question. Let me know what you think about it